# Which people are considered to be the founders of Projective Geometry?

Tags: reference-request, mathematics-social-history, projective-geometry

What were the fundamental principles and ideas of projective geometry that made people consider it groundbreaking and separates it from the rest of the geometry?  I would love to learn about a good book on projective geometry I could read.

Comment: See [Projective Geometry: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry#History): Desargues and Pascal, with early contribution from Pappus.

Comment: See also Meighan Dillon, [Geometry Through History: Euclidean, Hyperbolic, and Projective Geometries (2018 Springer)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Geometry_Through_History/IoBSDwAAQBA)

Answer (score 2):

While the wiki article mentions Desargues, it is inaccurate in that it implies that Desargues only had the notion of a point at infinity, whereas he went much further, including the line at infinity.  A series of recent papers (not mentioned in the wiki articles) tries to give Desargues the proper credit, as he went amazingly far:

> Anglade, Marie; Briend, Jean-Yves Nombrils, bruslans, autrement
> foyerz: la géométrie projective en action dans le Brouillon Project de
> Girard Desargues.  Arch. Hist. Exact Sci. 76 (2022), no. 2, 173–206.

> Briend, Jean-Yves Mathématiques en perspective: Desargues, la Hire,
> le Poîvre.  Arch. Hist. Exact Sci. 75 (2021), no. 6, 699–736.

> Anglade, Marie; Briend, Jean-Yves Le diamètre et la traversale: dans
> l'atelier de Girard Desargues.  Arch. Hist. Exact Sci. 73 (2019),
> no. 4, 385–426.

> Anglade, Marie; Briend, Jean-Yves La notion d'involution dans le
> Brouillon project de Girard Desargues.  Arch. Hist. Exact Sci. 71
> (2017), no. 6, 543–588.